# How to default Edge extension to show next to address bar by default

Tags: microsoft-edge, browser-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

Our company has ported a Chrome extension to Edge. The extension works fine, but there is a lot of important content in the popup itself. Edge extensions seem to only show the popup button if you toggle "show button next to the address bar" in the extension settings. This is generally a bad user experience, and not at all intuitive for our demographic.

Is it possible to default the extension to always show next to the address bar on install? Either via the manifest or in code somewhere?

Based on the information I've found online so far, it seems that the answer is "no", but maybe someone has a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to `manifest.json`:

```
"browser_specific_settings": {
  "edge": {
    "browser_action_next_to_addressbar": true
  }
}
```

see [Supported manifest keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/supported-manifest-keys#recommended-keys)

Comment: As a user, how to make the extension to show next to address bar ? Every time I install a new extension, I have to find it in a long menu, which is frustrating.